# Deleting files in Laravel local storage

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I store images in local storage and keep them in database but when deleted in database I want them to be deleted also in my local storage.

In short, I need to check if there is such an id in the database and accordingly I want to delete the file that belongs to that id.

`blade`

```
<input type="file" name="company" id="company" />
<input type="file" name="tax_plate" id="tax_plate" />
```

`Controller`

```
 $customer_id = DB::table('customers')->insertGetId([
    'fullname'   => request('fullname'),
    'tax_tc'     => request('tax_tc'),
   
]);
 CustomerDetail::create([
    'customer_id'         => $customer_id,
    'company'             => $request->company->hashName(),
    'tax_plate'           => $request->tax_plate->hashName(),
]);

$now = Carbon::now();
$year = $now->year;
$month = $now->month;
$fileStore = $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $customer_id;

$request->company->store($fileStore);
$request->tax_plate->store($fileStore);
```

[image]

Comment: Does it save the same id in database as well?

Comment: Probably easiest to add the file path to the database aswell "2020/2/1/xxx.jpg" and then create an observer for the model with a destroy handler that deletes that file on model deletion event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravels facade `Storage` like this:

```
Storage::delete($image);
```

or you could use this:

```
unlink(storage_path('app/images/'.$image));
```

If you wanna delete a directory so you could use this:

```
rmdir(storage_path('app/folder/'.$folder);
```

One important thing to mention is that you should first check whether the file or directory exists or not.

So if you wanna delete a image you should probably do this:

```
if(is_file($image))
{
    // 1. possibility
    Storage::delete($image);
    // 2. possibility
    unlink(storage_path('app/images/'.$image));
}
else
{
```

And if you wanna check whether it is a directory do this:

```
if(is_dir($image))
{
    // 1. possibility
    Storage::delete($images);
    // 2. possibility
    unlink(storage_path('app/folder/'.$images));
    // 3. possibility
    rmdir(storage_path('app/folder/'.$images));
}
else
{
    echo "Images folder does not exist";
}

    echo "Image does not exist";
}
```